# regex to detect the last line with floating point number or n/a

Tags: java, regex

I have text as follows (using java)

```
 HrtBrn n/a
 Regurg n/a
 ChestP 8.3
 Cough n/a
 Belch n/a
 Other 0.0
 Epigastric Pain n/a
 Throat Burn n/a
 Vomiting n/a
 Stomach Pain n/a
A load of other stuff and text
 HrtBrn n/a
 Regurg n/a
 ChestP 8.3
 Cough n/a
 Belch n/a
 Other 0.0
```

but this can also be

```
 HrtBrn n/a
 Regurg n/a
 ChestP 8.3
 Cough n/a
 Belch n/a
 Other 0.0
some other text blabla
 HrtBrn n/a
 Regurg n/a
 ChestP 8.3
```

It always starts with `HrtBrn` but and the end always finished with either a decimal number or n/a but the word on the final line can vary. I would like to get the chunk of text between HrtBrn and the next line that does not have either a decimal or n/a on it eg in the first example above I would like to capture

```
     HrtBrn n/a
     Regurg n/a
     ChestP 8.3
     Cough n/a
     Belch n/a
     Other 0.0
     Epigastric Pain n/a
     Throat Burn n/a
     Vomiting n/a
     Stomach Pain n/a
```

I am having trouble getting a capture to include the 'either decimal or n/a'- I can get up to the last decimal (so in both examples above I get up to `'Other 0.0'`) with `HrtBrn.*\d+\.(\d*|n\/a)` but I can't get the last n/a with this
Here is my regex

Comment: So first example should match upto `Stomach Pain n/a`?

Comment: Yes it should to include the n/a as well

Comment: It will either end with a decimal number or n/a but not both if that's what you mean

Comment: No, I am asking can there be multiple start-end blocks in the same input?

Comment: No there will only be one start end block in the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to match with `DOTALL` flag:

```
HrtBrn.*?\n[^\n]* +(?:\d+\.\d+|n/a)(?!\s+[^\n]* +(?:\d+\.\d+|n/a))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nA1qH9/3)

This will match till last line which ends in a decimal number or `n/a`.

Comment: Does that match to the last line before the normal text? Now I understand your other question- there can be another list with n/a (not necessarily with HrtBrn) after the normal text. I should have been clearer

Comment: If you update the question with that kind if input then I will try to rework my regex.